# Unit Test Error Using System Admin Profile: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, Unable to create/update fields: Name. Please check the security settings

Tags: unit-test, permissions, account, servicecloud, dmlexception

I'm getting this error when creating an Account inside a Test class. **I'm using the System Admin profile** to execute the tests, and **this profile has permission** to edit the Account Name field (mentioned in the error).

I've checked the permissions twice and I have access to the field. What could be causing this?

Also, the Account object is not a child of a Master Detail relationship, so reaparenting isn't the cause. The Name field is a normal text field (is not autogenerated). If I leave it blank, I get another error saying that it can't be null.

[image]

Thank you so much, any advice is appreciated.

Code details:

Account creation:
[image]

Test helper method:
[image]

Comment: You should use [edit] and show your testmethod code and the line where this error occurs

Comment: Hi @cropredy I've added the code I'm using. It's pretty basic, that's why it surprises me that isn't working. Thank you! any advice is well received.

Comment: please don't use screen shots - use [edit] and the code formatting tool -- this makes it easier for the answerer to copy paste your code into the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `PATIENT_RT_ID` corresponds to a `Person` type (which seems likely), then `Name` is never writable by any `Profile`. You instead set `FirstName` and `LastName`.

This behavior is [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_account.htm):

> If the account has a record type of Person Account:
>
> This value is the concatenation of the FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, and Suffix of the associated person contact.
>
> You can't modify this value.

Comment: Thank you Adrian, that was it. I'm not used to work with person accounts and they peculiarities, but this worked and helped me a lot. Regards!